# System.IO.IOException: Connection timed out In Mailkit

Tags: c#, .net-core, imap, mailkit

I used MailKit.Net.Imap to read email in my mail box.

Sometimes I get an exception like that I shared below

**System.IO.IOException: Connection timed out ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Connection timed out at MailKit.Net.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---**

Is there any suggistion to solve this problem?

```
   ImapClient client;
  
    client = new ImapClient();
    client.Timeout= (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Also, I can use timeout property of Imap, this can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Increase the timeout using the `ImapClient.Timeout` property. (That said, 1 minute is *less* than the default timeout which is 2 minutes)
2. As Max points out in the comments below, properly handle exceptions and retry (which often will require reconnecting the `ImapClient`).

Comment: To improve this value, is there any problem on server memory like cache and ram?
Will be any performance problem?

Comment: That would depend on the server, but I doubt it.

Comment: If you’re getting a connection timeout in a minute either the server is extremely heavily overloaded (unlikely), or you’re having a connection/routing blip.  Catch the exception, wait a few moments, then try again.  All internet using services need a loop; as connections go down all the time.

Comment: What Max said is absolutely true. For the past 2 years, I worked at Microsoft on its Azure platform and I can tell you that one of the biggest faults we had to handle were network connectivity issues even between our extremely high-speed networked servers. You CANNOT take your network connection for granted.

Comment: My application have to check mail address to detect is there a new email according to my email filter as continuously. In this point, what Can I do? First one Create a singleton imapClient connection and refresh this until an error occured, the second one, dispose the  imap connection and create new one  at regular intervals

Comment: @jstedfast what do you think my last comment? Thanks a lot for your interest by the way ...